# How can I set a network connection to use the AES encryption method on a Windows Mobile device?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, configurationmanager

I am trying to configure a network connection using ConfigurationManager.ProcessConfiguration, with the configuration file as specified in the MSDN [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bb737539.aspx). I can create a connection, and configure all of the settings correctly except for the encryption type. No matter what I choose, it is always set to TKIP. I need to set it to AES, which is the only other option in the drop-down menu for this property on the device.

The xml I'm sending looks like this (OMA device provisioning format):

```
<wap-provisioningdoc>
  <characteristic type="Wi-Fi">
    <characteristic type="access-point">
      <characteristic type="Name">
        <parm name="Authentication" value="4" />
        <parm name="Encryption" value="5" >
        <parm name="Hidden" value="1" />
      </characteristic>
    </characteristic>
  </characteristic>
</wap-provisioningdoc>
```

I've tried values of 0-5 for the 'Encryption' param, but none of these have any effect.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the *undocumented* AES value for the Encryption parameter.

```
<parm name="Encryption" value="6" >
```